# Idempotency with Redis in multi-threaded envirnment

Tags: spring, redis, idempotent

I'm creating a POST api in which I'm using **REDIS** for idempotency.

I'm taking a `idempotency-key` in header which is getting saved in Redis.

When the same request comes in, I'm returning the cached message.

In redis I'm saving it as `idempotency-key: message-body with Http status`

During load testing I sent the same request, with same idempotency-key 30 times.

As expected, 5/30 times, the same request was stored in Redis, because new request comes in before the first finished.

In redis, how can I avoid it, without making API slow?

I did not find much material on net.

Apart for redis I only have dynamo as a centralized DB.

Answer (score 0):

> In redis, how can I avoid it, without making API slow?

By locking on the idempotency key when you **start** processing the request.

The goal of idempotency is not only always returning same response, but also ensuring that the action was executed exactly once and not multiple times.